# Read value from an array in rb to an erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, erb

I have a global array in Ruby having some string objects. Something like:

```
$my_array = ['apple', 'orange', 'cherries']
```

In every ERB file, I wish to read one object out of this array. So in my ERB file, I used: `"<%= $my_array[0] %>"` and this doesn't work. The error I get is `"undefined method [] for nil:NilClass"`. But when I print `$my_array` while debugging, I see the values are present inside the array. So looks like ERB is not reading the array from Ruby.

But if I have a global variable in Ruby, eg: `$my_var = "This is a text"` and reading this from ERB as `"<%= $my_var %>"` works great.

How do I read a global array from Ruby to ERB?

Comment: How and where is `$my_array` defined? Are you sure that before loading the view it gets instantiated? A few code snippets about it can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also use a CONSTANT as an alternative like following..

```
MY_ARRAY = ["apple", "orange", "cherries"]
```

and it will work:

```
MY_ARRAY[0] => "apple"
MY_ARRAY.first => "apple"
```

or simple variable

```
@my_array = ["apple", "orange", "cherries"]
```

will also work:

```
@my_array[0] => "apple"
@my_array.first => "apple"
@my_array.last => "cherries"
```